Using beta function

An electronic device manufacturing company is evaluating the reliability of its new
smartwatch model. The proportion of smartwatches requiring service during the first
year of operation is modeled as a random variable that follows a Beta distribution with
parameters α = 3.5 and β = 2.2.


a. What is the probability that less than 30% of new smartwatch models sold this year require service during their first year of operation?


b. What is the value d, such that the probability that 50% of smartwatches require service?
during your first year?


c. Determine the probability that exactly 80% of new smartwatch models
require service during their first year of operation

using R :
alpha <- 3.5
beta <- 2.2


p_a <- pbeta(0.3, alpha, beta)
print(p_a)


d <- dbeta(0.5, alpha, beta)
print(d)


pdf_c <- pbeta(0.8, alpha, beta)
print(pdf_c)

output:
[1] 0.06087717
[1] 1.524097
[1] 0.8187363

Does using math technique give you the same answer?
